# How to create a Desktop Shortcut for all users in Ubuntu 14.04 for AD joined machine

Tags: shortcuts, .desktop, active-directory

I'm looking to create a simple shortcut to a folder that will appear on all users desktops when they login into an Ubuntu 14.04 machine. The machine has been joined to a Microsoft AD.

Help appreciated.

Answer (score 5):

For new users, you could place a symlink to the desired directory into `/etc/skel/Desktop`. Note that you may adapt the `Desktop` directory name depending on your locale.

For all users in general, create a root owned `.desktop` file in `/etc/xdg/autostart` folder for all users to access, and for `Exec=` line , create a symbolic link to the program you want users to access. For instance,

`bash -c 'ln -s /usr/share/applications/gedit.desktop /home/$USER/Desktop/gedit-link'`

Note, the above exaple uses as `gedit.desktop` just as an example; adapt as necessary for your specific case. The link will be created on user's desktop every time they log in.

Comment: Many thank, although I have now appear to locked my self out of the machine (http://askubuntu.com/questions/663498/just-joind-a-machine-to-an-ad-domain-and-have-seeminly-lock-myself-out). If get back in I will try.