# How to create a shortcut for all users?

Tags: openvpn, shortcuts, multiple-users

**Ingles**

Dear,

Good morning, we want to implement in the user profiles already generated a shortcut on the desktop where an OpenVPN terminal is being run with the following command:

```
openvpn --config sample.ovpn
```

Is it possible to find something similar to windows `C:\Users\Public\Desktop`?

I checked the following thread and I don't think it meets what we need:
[How to create a desktop shortcut for all users in ubuntu 14.04 for ad joined mac](https://askubuntu.com/questions/663491/how-to-create-a-desktop-shortcut-for-all-users-in-ubuntu-14-04-for-ad-joined-mac)

Sorry for the bad wording in English.

Version: Ubuntu 18.04

Thanks!

---

---

---

**UPDATE 22/07/2020**

Español:

Estimados,

Al final terminamos optando por hacerlo desde Ansible. Si bien con lo del directorio Skel que en cada perfil nuevo que se crea, se genera el acceso directo, nos está faltando el playbook/config para que dicho acceso sea copiado a todos los perfiles existentes.

El destino del archivo sería home/*/Desktop(Escritorio) pero me termina generando una carpeta el nombre "*".

¿Algún experto en Ansible que pueda guiarme?

Gracias!

---

Ingles:

Dears,

In the end we ended up choosing to do it from Ansible. Although with the Skel directory that in each new profile that is created, the direct access is generated, we are missing the playbook/config so that said access is copied to all existing profiles.

The destination of the file would be home/*/Desktop(Escritorio) but it ends up generating a folder with the name "*".

Any Ansible expert who can guide me?

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

**Desktop icon**
It is not possible to add a `.desktop` launcher to all desktops of different users at once. You need to place a file in the "Desktop" folder of each users. That can be scripted, though, to automate the process.

**Application menu**

A better way, both from a sysadmin *and* user point of view, would be to put the launcher in `/usr/share/applications`. That way, it will be immediately available in the Application Overview of all users. Then the user can decide for himself

- whether to put it in the Dock for easy access,
- or to copy it to his desktop for easy access.